# Search Bar Text class entry in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to know if what's the class entry in sublime Text, because I want to change the font of it, it's kinda thin and I can't see it clearly  ? 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Go to,
**Preferences -> Settings** Then in right tab (user setting) add a new key
"font_face": "Arial", and save the setting.

Comment: not helpful at alll I'm referring to the font of the search bar ? not the font of the editor, the search bar only, It's kinda thin and it's not very clear for the eyes.